# Would be or Would have been, and why?

Tags: conditional-constructions, perfect-constructions, will-would

1. He *would be* a king, unfortunately he died due to a disease
2. He *would have been* a king, unfortunately he died due to a disease

*Would be* or *Would have been*, and why?

Answer (score 2):

We don't usually use *would be* when speaking of a deceased person.

We can say *He would be President [now] if he had won the election.*

... but we say *He would have been King if he had not died before ascending the throne.*